# Switching screen sessions from inside an existing session

Tags: gnu-screen

I've tried a bunch of commands but they all attach the session into the current session and they as you can imagine it bails when I try to reattach it later as it's already attached in the session nest.

I create sessions for each project I work on with windows to remote servers, logs and vim.
But everytime I want to switch I have to  C-a d then screen -DR

I'd rather be able to just type a single command.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK this is not possible with `screen` and I know of no way to easily work around this limitation. The issue here is that each `screen` session is independent and has no knowledge of other sessions.

If this is a feature you will use often, I would recommend switching to `tmux` which does this with `<C-b>s`. I've used both `screen` and `tmux` extensively and have not regretted favoring `tmux` this past year whenever a terminal multiplexer was called for.

On a side note running nested screen sessions is not too difficult, just send two escapes and commands go to the inner screen session, it helps if the escape is a single character, I like:

```
escape ``
```